# Unity WebGL Responsive content

Tags: unity, webgl, ui-design

I was trying to develop a simple drag and drop items for Web. What I was trying to do is to make the UI elements from web view to mobile view when the aspect ratio is changes.

[image]

I need this web view change to mobile view as below when the screen changes.
[image]

Changing Canvas settings does not seems to be work. Could someone please help with this issue?